# How to write Flink Streaming data into Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to implement a Flink Streaming job to consume the data from Kafka and then write the data into Azure Blob Storage, I have a hadoop cluster (yarn) and then I run Flink on it, I submit the flink streaming job on that yarn cluster, but I got an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getPassword(Ljava/lang/String;)[C
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.ShellDecryptionKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(ShellDecryptionKeyProvider.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.getAccountKeyFromConfiguration(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:934)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1023)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:507)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1281)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2397)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.Utils.createTaskExecutorContext(Utils.java:398)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnApplicationMasterRunner.runApplicationMaster(YarnApplicationMasterRunner.java:316)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnApplicationMasterRunner$1.call(YarnApplicationMasterRunner.java:194)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnApplicationMasterRunner$1.call(YarnApplicationMasterRunner.java:191)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnApplicationMasterRunner.run(YarnApplicationMasterRunner.java:191)
at org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnApplicationMasterRunner.main(YarnApplicationMasterRunner.java:124)
```

If anyone knows how to integrate Flink with Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: you are most likely using separate versions of the library when compiling and running. Make sure you have the right version

Comment: I'm using Microsoft HDI Hadoop cluster, we cannot change the hadoop version and yarn version of this cluster. Flink version is 1.4.2, according to the log, it looks like Flink use Hadoop 2.4.1 while HDI Hadoop version is 2.7.3. Anybody know which version of Flink I should use? Thanks a lot

Comment: I changed the version of maven-shade-plugin, and start a long-running Flink cluster on YARN, then submit the flink streaming job, it works right now

Comment: please update the answer in answer section so that it helps other users. upvote appreciated.